# Connecting a model to .csv file

Tags: cakephp, csv, datasource

This is the first time I'm doing this and I'm kinda stuck on a close deadline.

I am trying to read a list of forbidden words for my input from a .csv file into an array. Here's where I am now...

The .csv file is named `forbidden.csv` and it is placed in `app/webroot/files/`

I downloaded the [CsvSource](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/CsvSource.php) file from github and placed it in `app/Model/DataSource/`.

Then I added it in `app/Config/database.php`:

```
public $csv = array(
    'datasource' => 'CsvSource',
    'path' => 'files',
);
```

This is my Csv model:

```
class Csv extends AppModel {

    public $useDbConfig = 'csv';

}
```

By debugging in the connect function of CsvSource, I found out that `'files'` was the only way to read the path, and I don't know how to set the filename afterwards. Here's the debug and the result:

*CsvSource.php, line 128*

```
$this->connection = new Folder($this->config['path'], $create, $mode);
debug($this->connection);
```

*output:*

```
object(Folder) {
    path => 'C:\wamp\www\gallery\app\webroot\files'
    sort => false
    mode => (int) 493
    [protected] _messages => array()
    [protected] _errors => array()
    [protected] _directories => null
    [protected] _files => null
}
```

So, how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model:

```
public $useTable = 'someFileName';
```

See [line 193](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/CsvSource.php#L193) of the data source:

```
$filename = $model->table . '.' . $this->config['extension'];
```

You'll have to change the extension via config if it is not csv.